# Reinstall SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, installation, sharepoint-administration

I have a simple 3 server farm. I would like to reinstall SharePoint on the existing servers. I'm not sure of the steps involved and could use some guidance. There is no search or MMS. No excel Services either. I do use hosted apps that are hosted locally on my network. 
When I initially installed the farm I used very slow drives. There was trouble from the start because of this. 
I'm thinking that I should dismount the content databases and manually rebuild the services and readd the trust to our hosted app server.

EDIT: I must not have been clear. The farm servers have already been migrated to faster drives. I am asking questions about how to do a rebuild. Is it just amatter of removing the content DBS, uninstalling SharePoint, reinstalling SP, adding the custom farm features, and remounting the content databases?

Comment: Can you give more details of your infrastructure? Are you in a virtualized environment? Do you mean that you would re-install servers because of hard drive size?

Comment: Yes, it is all virtualized. The drive space allocated was abysmally slow and I had timeouts during the install of the binaries. These virtual have since been moved to faster drives. My concern is that despite being on the faster drives this farm still has problems, not the least of which is one with the distributed cache service.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a virtualized environment it would be easier to migrate the VMs to a host with faster storage.

Answer (score 0):

When the farm was intially setup the drives were slow. They have since been moved onto faster storage. However there are still issues with this farm which is why I'm thinking that it might be better to remove sharepoint from the servers and reinstall it, creating a new config db in the process, then reattach the content databases.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can follow the same process guidelines of a farm upgrade ([2013 to 2016](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/upgrade-and-update/upgrade-to-sharepoint-server-2016)).

The high level process is:

1. Building the new farm from scratch in parallel with MINIMUM services and isolated DNS records (eg: hosts file) for all your Web Applications URLs (including Alternate Access Mapping URLs)
2. Installing latest CUs
3. Installing your custom server side solution (WSP) if any
4. Making your old farm in read only
5. Making backups of your Content Databases and Service Databases you want to imports
6. Restoring your databases into your target SQL Server instance (attention make sure you will use same service accounts as previously otherwise you’ll have some troubles)
7. Upgrading Services ([similar process than 2016](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/upgrade-and-update/upgrade-service-applications-to-sharepoint-server-2016))
8. Creating Web Application and attach/upgrade Content Databases ([similar process than 2016](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/upgrade-and-update/upgrade-content-databases))
9. Bringing the new farm online by updating DNS records to point on the new SharePoint front end(s)
10. Planning the decommission process of your old farm (grace period if anything goes wrong)

Note: if you are able to have a “long” downtime, the steps 5/6 can be replaced by : dismounting databases from SharePoint then dismounting all of them from the old sql instance then move or copy sql files at the new location, finally attach them to the new sql instance.